# tridiagonal form for householder's

Tags: numerical-methods

How can we use Householder's method to place the following matrix in tridiagonal form?

$$A =\pmatrix{4  & -1  & -1 & 0 \\
              -1  & 4 &  0  & -1 \\
              -1  & 0  & 4  & -1 \\
               0  & -1 & -1 & 4} $$

Basically, I'm stuck on understanding the method and am trying to understand how to do it with this matrix. Thanks

So I can only really understand of getting S and R from column 1

Comment: Can you describe what you have tried and where you are getting stuck? Regards

Comment: Basically, I am stuck on really understanding the Householder's method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your matrix as
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}4&u^T\\ u&\ast\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $u^T=(-1,-1,0)$. Let $Q_3$ be the **3-by-3** Householder matrix whose first column is $u/\|u\|$ (please review your lecture notes or textbook to see how to construct such a matrix $Q_3$). Then
$$
A':=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ &Q_3^T\end{pmatrix}A\begin{pmatrix}1\\ &Q_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&\begin{array}{c}\|u\|&0&0\end{array}\\ \begin{array}{c}\|u\|\\0\\ 0\end{array}&\Large B\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In other words, we use a Householder matrix to zero out all but the first two entries in the first row and first column of $A$. Then you may proceed recursively. However, since $A$ is only 4-by-4 in this example, we need only one more iteration. Let
$$
B=\begin{pmatrix}\ast&v^T\\ v&\ast\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $v$ is a $2$-vector. Find a 2-by-2 Householder matrix $Q_2$ whose first column is $v/\|v\|$. Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}1\\&Q_2^T\end{pmatrix}B\begin{pmatrix}1\\&Q_2^T\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\ast&\|v\|&0\\ \|v\|&\ast&\ast\\0&\ast&\ast\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Again, we use a Householder matrix to zero out all except the first two entries in the first row and first column of $B$. Now
$$
A'':=\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\\&&Q_2^T\end{pmatrix}A'\begin{pmatrix}1\\&1\\&&Q_2^T\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4&\|u\|&0&0\\ \|u\|&\ast&\|v\|&0\\ 0&\|v\|&\ast&\ast\\0&0&\ast&\ast\end{pmatrix}
$$
is tridiagonal.

Comment: Can you add some more detail to this? I want to learn it from this example. Thanks

Comment: @BuddyHolly Except for the construction of real orthogonal matrices with given first columns (i.e. the construction of $Q_3$ and $Q_2$), I have already included every detail here. Perhaps you could tell me the part that you do not understand.

Comment: Construction of Q2 and Q3 and the norms v for the matricies.

Comment: @BuddyHolly See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/242165/1551) to another question.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the Householder method to tridiagonalize a matrix. Basically the Householder transformation is doing this:
[image: Householder]

I think it is the best if you write where you started with the algorithm of doing this and then I can help you.

Comment: sorry i can't see any step

Comment: Interesting picture! Where can I see more of it? (not necessarily about this particular topic)